# How to concat two JS arrays to a new array of objetcs as key: value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

We have 2 arrays like:

```
foo = ['one', 'two', 'three']
bar = ['morning', 'day', 'night']
```

How could i get a new array of objects, which should looks like:

```
obj = [{'one': 'morning'}, {'two': 'day'}, {'three': 'night'}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: looping through the arrays is one option

Comment: When you don't know any funky magical way, just write a 2 lines loop...

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function doing this.

I would do it like:

```
var list = {};

for(var i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i) {
    list[foo[i]] = bar[i];
}
```

Maybe you should do a little bit security stuff like if(bar[i]) and so on.

More secure would be something like:

```
var list = {};
var len = Math.min(foo.length(), bar.length());

for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(!list[foo[i]]) {
        list[foo[i]] = bar[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the arrays and load the key/value pairs into an object.

```
var foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    bar = ['morning', 'day', 'night'],
    obj = {},
    i;

for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    obj[foo[i]] = bar[i];
}
```

And now you should have

```
obj = [{'one': 'morning'}, {'two': 'day'}, {'three': 'night'}]
```

Note: this solution assumes that both arrays are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this method fit for you

```
Array.prototype.join_array = function(keys, val){
    if (arguments.length < 2 ) return {};


    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++ ){

        var o = {};
        o[ keys[i] ] = val[i] || val[val.length -1];
        this.push( o );

    }
};

var a = [];
a.join_array( ['key1', 'key2'], ['val1', 'val2'] );
console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );
```